# odoo13 A question of creating customer when i archive this rule "res.partner.rule.private.employee"

Tags: odoo

i want to archive this rule "res.partner.rule.parivate.employee"（['|', ('type', '!=', 'private'), ('type', '=', False)]）to make sure users can see his own customers by other rules; but after i archived this rule, the system raised AccessError "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5on6m.png)" when i create customer and open Personal center by normal user(no admin).
i tried to rewrite this rule and debug this rule, but i can't see what raise out; i have no idea for this question;
There's something missing here but I don't know what. Any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

add a rule ['|', ('user_id','=',user.id), ('id', '=', user.partner_id.id)]